# Get a dict from a python list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list `my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and I need to create a dictionary which looks like

```
{ 'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
  'b': ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd'], 
  'c': ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd'], 
  'd': ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c'] }
```

each element as its value being the list but the first element is itself.

Here is my code

```
my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
my_dict=dict()

for x in my_list:        
    n = my_lst[:]
    n.remove(x)
    n= [x] + n[:]
    my_dict[x] = n

print my_dict
```

which gives

```
{'1': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 
 '3': ['3', '1', '2', '4'], 
 '2': ['2', '1', '3', '4'], 
 '4': ['4', '1', '2', '3']}
```

as required. 
But I don't think that's the most optimal way of doing it. Any help to optimize will be appreciated.

Comment: do you need to use lists absolutely? appart from the key element having to come first, does the order of the remaining ones need to stay the same as the original list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> seq
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> {e: [e]+[i for i in seq if i != e] for e in seq}
    {'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
     'b': ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd'],
     'c': ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd'],
     'd': ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 2):

A faster approach (than the accepted answer) for larger lists is

```
{e: [e] + seq[:i] + seq[i+1:] for i, e in enumerate(seq)}
```

Relative timings:

```
In [1]: seq = list(range(1000))

In [2]: %timeit {e: [e]+[i for i in seq if i != e] for e in seq}
10 loops, best of 3: 40.8 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit {e: [e] + seq[:i] + seq[i+1:] for i, e in enumerate(seq)}
100 loops, best of 3: 6.03 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get hacky with a dictionary comprehension:

```
my_dict = {elem: list(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x != elem)) for elem in my_lst}
```

This works on the fact that the `sorted` function performs a stable sort, and `False` is less than `True`

Edit: This method is less clear and probably slower, use with caution.

Comment: 3 times slower on my PC